# migrating to sql native client causes question marks on db

Tags: c++, unicode, sql-server-native-client

we have migrated to native sql server 10. since then everything that pass throw the c++ code to the data
base with unicode character such as Hebrew turned into question mark. before the migration everything worked fine. any idea why this is happens?

thanks

EDIT:
Connection string builder:

```
 res =  _T("Provider=") + sprovider +
            _T(";Data Source=") + data_source +
            _T(";Initial Catalog=") + initial_catalog +
            _T(";User Id=") + username +
            _T(";Password=") + password;

res += _T(";DataTypeCompatibility=80");
```

as for other places in the code we use it is used in a very wide context. it is very hard to show examples with a system as big as this. any way i can a sure you it worked fine before with unicode , this are nor a new tables

Comment: I guess the character encoding differs in the new database. I mean the encoding of the corresponding field is set to something like ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8.

Comment: no, i forgot to mention that we have another side that uses .NET driver and it enters unicode charcters just fine. also checking with sql management gives me good result

Comment: still has to be a character encoding issue at some point of the system. Could you please provide some wider look on the subject?

Comment: what you mean by wider look?

Comment: e.g where you experience the issue? i mean i should see the relevant part of the system structure to say anything usable. What kind of code connects to the database, through what library, where does it write the problematic text, etc, etc, etc.. :)

Comment: edited. i cannot supply more info. :(